# Windows Grep detect specific process according to TaskMnge / ProcessEplorer

Tags: windows, grep

I have a program that runs several times in parallel on Windows.
I want to get information from it's command line that he started with.
I saw on Process explorer that can present that information.
I need something like grep in Unix but efficiently does the job with out holding a lot of CPU.
I want to get information according to some data that is in the command line.
How can I:

1) take that information ?
2) Is it pre4sented only in Process Explorer isn't a WMI that will bring that directly ?
3) Does it cost a lot of CPU ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify on what you're actually after? What is the goal?

Comment: As I already wrote: I want to get information according to some data that is in the command line.

Comment: Well, that's still pretty vague. Anyhow, I didn't -1 you, but that reflects the fact that I'm not the only one thinking that you should structure you question differently so people would understand it.

Answer (score 3):

You can;

```
WMIC PROCESS get Caption, Commandline, Processid
```

Or filtered;

```
WMIC PROCESS WHERE "Caption='some.exe'" get Caption, Commandline, Processid
```

add `> some.file` or use wmic's `/OUTPUT:some.file` to dump it to a file.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742610.aspx